# rewrite Code without pattern

Tags: haskell

How Can I rewrite this Code without pattern Matching:

```
    data StringList = NilSL
        | ConsSL String StringList

    f2 [] = []
    f2 (x:xs) = if elem '?' x then ["F:" ++ x] : f2 (xs) else [x] : f2 (xs)
```

I already write something like this, but I only get an error.

```
    import Data.Char

    data StringList = NilSL
        | ConsSL String StringList

    f2 [] = 0 
    f2 x = if elem '?' x then ["F:" ++ (head x)] : f2 (tail x) else (x : f2 (tail x)
```

What is wrong here?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: soemthing very Long:

Comment: Please include it in the question text (use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43844648/edit) button).

Comment: * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `[a] -> [a]'
      Expected type: ([a] -> [a]) -> [Char] -> [Char]
        Actual type: [Char] -> [Char]
    * Relevant bindings include
        f2 :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [Char] -> [Char9
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
      Expected type: [Char]
        Actual type: [[Char]]
    * In the expression: x : f2 tail x
  In the expression:
        if elem '?' x then "F:" ++ head x : f2 tail x else x : f2 tail x
      In an equation for `f2':
          f2 x
            = if elem '?' x then "F:" ++ head x : f2 tail x else x : f2 tail x

Comment: I dont really understand what it say

Comment: the code you gave will not produce the error from your comments - it will just complain about `[Char]` vs `Char` and it's easy to see why, as you have `elem '?' x` => `x ~ [Char]` but then `"F:" ++ head x` => `x ~ [[Char]]` and now the type checker cannot unify `Char` with `[Char]`

Answer (score 1):

#### remark:

I think your *task*/*exercise* is to rewrite this using a *higher-order function* - in this case it seems to be a simple `map`:

```
f2 = map check
  where
    check xs =
      if elem '?' xs
      then "F:" ++ xs
      else xs
```

---

#### but just in case here is how to fix yours:

```
f2 [] = []
f2 xss =
  if elem '?' (head xss)
  then ["F:" ++ head xss] : f2 (tail xss)
  else [head xss] : f2 (tail xss)
```

changes are:

- `f2 [] = []` not `= 0`
- `elem '?' x` to `elem '?' head x`
- `else (x : ...` to `else [head x] ..`
- also renamed `x` into `xss` to indicate that it's a list of lists

---

basically all I did was replace `head xss` in where there pattern matching one had `x` and `tail xss` where it had `xs`